# Are JSON nested objects necessary?

Tags: json

I have a question about the way JSON is written. Which is better in terms of usability? I am trying to use a single JSON file for decoding in PHP and Swift, and was wondering which would be the better way for the JSON to be written. Nested objects or no nested objects, essentially.

**Option 1**

```
  {
    "title": "Test",
    "image": "image",
    "imageCard": "imae2",
    "count": 20,
    "section": "personal",
    "description": "Description",
    "color": "#F17B08",
    "content": {
      "video": true,
      "text": true,
      "updated": false
    },
    "homepage": {
      "featured": false,
      "popular": false,
      "new": false
    },
    "levels": "7-12"
  }
]
```

**Option 2**

```
[
  {
    "title": "Test",
    "image": "image",
    "imageCard": "imae2",
    "count": 20,
    "section": "personal",
    "description": "Description",
    "color": "#F17B08",
    "video": true,
    "text": true,
    "updated": false,
    "featured": false,
    "popular": false,
    "new": false,
    "levels": "7-12"
  }
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong about complex objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JSON structure is often bound to be mapped to an object-oriented **class**. The closer the JSON structure is from the **Model** of your program (all the classes, and how each has one or many relationships to others), the easier it will be to deserialize the response from the API.

Now, JSON nesting is **necessary** just as much as you make *associations, compositions*  and *aggregations* with your classes.

Let's say you have a `Student` that has a name, an unique ID and a `Teacher` which gives many `Courses`

Having a **nested** JSON such as:

```
[
    {
        "Name":"John Doe",
        "ID":"948AFF",
        "Teacher":{
            "John Nash",
            "Classes":[
                {...},
                {...},
                {...}
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "Name":"William Smooth",
        "ID":"123LMLG",
        "Teacher":{
            "Ulrich Stokes",
            "Classes":[
                {...},
                {...},
                {...}
            ]
        }
    }   
]
```

Is an intuitive, clean, flexible way to structure the JSON. Because it maps easily to your model. Each element of the array is an instance of a `Student` which has an instance of `Teacher`, which has a list of `Courses`.

Whereas if you had a **flat** structure like you suggest :

```
[
    {
        "Name":"John Doe",
        "ID":"948AFF",
        "TeacherName":"John Nash",
        "ClassesOfTheTeacher":[
            {...},
            {...},
            {...}
        ]

    },
    {
        "Name":"William Smooth",
        "ID":"123LMLG",
        "TeacherName":"Ulrich Stokes",
        "ClassesOfTheTeacher":[
            {...},
            {...},
            {...}
        ]
    }   
]
```

Forces you to systematically map each field to the attribute of one of your classes. It doesn't stick easily to your model, you have to make some manipulations to map this to your model.

Furthermore, what if suddenly you wanted to have .. 3 `Teachers` for each student ? Would you end up with TeacherName1, TeacherName2, TeacherName3, and ClassesOfTheTeacher1, ClassesOfTheTeacher2, etc. ? Probably not.

**Nested JSON is necessary if you have association/composition/aggregation in your classes.**